# ARRAYFORMULA COUNT number of rows matching a source column where destination column CONTAINS source string in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a table (`input table`) with some columns where one column has text.

I have another table (`query table`) with some query strings.

For each row in `query table`, I want to see how many rows in `input table` have the `query` string.

## `query table`

| query | count |
| --- | --- |
| alpha |  |
| bravo |  |
| charlie delta |  |

## `input table`

| query | data |
| --- | --- |
| this is my alpha | one |
| I will bravo you | two |
| what is your name | three |
| how are you | four |
| she, charlie delta, said | five |
| one two charlie three alpha | six |

The expected output would be this:

| query | count |
| --- | --- |
| alpha | 2 |
| bravo | 1 |
| charlie delta | 1 |

I tried something like this, but it does not print the expected result. It prints `2` for all rows. I assume this is because it's just counting the first row in `query table` (`alpha`).

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
        A2:A <> "",
        COUNTIF(
            REGEXMATCH(`input table`!A:A, A2:A),
            TRUE     
        ),
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try with the `wildcard` search:*

```js
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
        A2:A <> "",
        COUNTIF(
            'input table'!A:A, "*"&A2:A&"*"), 
        ))
```